# Manipulating tm_mon in struct tm?

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding this program, namely the `tm_mon +1` part.

I am new to C and I normally always write my own little programs for any challenge I am set in the course book I am following but I've had to consult with someone else for a solution for this one (it is a mix of the course book and their code, so not mine) and I don't understand why `+1` is added to `tm_mon`. I understand that `tm_mon = January` but I'm not clear how the +1 makes a difference, and *why* it is +1 and not + 2 or any other number!

The program is designed to tell you what the date will be in 4 million seconds.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    long secondsToFuture = time(NULL) + 4000000;
    struct tm futureTime;
    localtime_r(&secondsToFuture, &futureTime);

    printf("The date in 4,000,000 seconds will be %d-%d-%d\n", futureTime.tm_mon + 1, futureTime.tm_mday, futureTime.tm_year + 1900);

    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate any help as I'm a bit stuck on this.

Comment: The `tm_mon` member is *zero-based*, that is January is zero and December is 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following table. As you can see tm_mon is a value from 0=january to 11=december.

[image]

'*' tm_sec is generally 0-59. The extra range is to accommodate for leap seconds in certain systems.

**EDIT**

Then in your case **without +1** in case of date 1/1/2015 the real output will be

```
The date in 4,000,000 seconds will be 0/1/2015
```

**With +1** will propel output

```
The date in 4,000,000 seconds will be 1/1/2015
```

Comment: Why can't the +1 be left out in the above? I understand it begins at 0, I'm just not sure what the +1 does.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Feeling pretty stupid that I didn't see that.

Comment: The range of `tm_sec` is 0-60, not 0-61. The 1989/1990 edition of the standard was written based on the incorrect assumption that there can be two leap seconds in the same minute; in fact, there can be only one. The error was corrected in the 1999 edition.